# Simplifying Logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am experiencing difficulty in simplifying the following equation:

$$\log_{2}\frac 8{125} \;- 3\log_{2}\frac 3{5} \; -4\log_{2}\frac 1{2}.$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the logarithm rules? If not, check [this link](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Logarithm.html) out for reference purposes.

Comment: To kick things off, you can begin by using the rule $k \cdot log (a) = log (a^k)$ to bring up the $3$ and $4$ as an exponent. In other words, we have $log_{2}((\frac{3}{5})^3)$ and $log_{2}((\frac{1}{2})^4)$. Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: What I was doing was simplifying the fractions so that they all had a denominator of 10. 8/125 cube root was 2/5 , then I ended up with 3log_2 4/10 - 3log_2 6/10 - 4log_2 5/10 ....thats where I'm stuck. I've seen the answer in the textbook as 7 - 3log_2 (3) but I don't know how to reach that.

Comment: I see. Well the community has provided you with *numerous* hints on how to approach your question. Hopefully your doubts can be answered after meticulously viewing the answers below.

Comment: Yes now it make complete sense to me. Thank you for your help and guidance.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rules of logs

$\log ab = \log a + \log b\\
\log \frac {a}{b} = \log a - \log b\\
\log a^n = n\log a$

They are really all the same rule... just presented differently..

To simplify, you will need to apply that second line to break up the fractions.

$\log 2^3 -\log 125 - 3\log 3+3\log 5 - 4 \log 1  +4\log 2$

$8 = 2^3$ and $125 = 5^3$ use the 3rd rule to simplify that, and the second one will cancel with the $3\log 5$ term.

$3\log 2 - 3\log 3 - 4 \log 1  +4\log 2$

What else $\log_2 2 = 1$ and $\log 1 = 0$

$7-3\log_2 3$

Comment: This has helped solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

$$\log ab=\log a+\log b$$
$$\log \frac{a}{b}=\log a-\log b$$
$$k\log a=\log a^k$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

$$\log_{2}\frac 8{125}=\log_{2}\frac {2^3}{5^3}=\log_2 2^3 - \log_25^3$$

$$3\log_{2}\frac 3{5}=3(\log_23 \,- \log_25) $$

$$4\log_{2}\frac 1{2}=-4\log_22$$